# Why is this method "undefined" in Firefox once the page has loaded?

Tags: javascript

```
"use strict";
Math.isNumber = function(number) {
    return (number >= 0 || number < 0);
};
```

I have placed the above in a clean HTML file within `<script>` tags within the `<head>`. Before the page has fully loaded, I can use `alert(Math.isNumber("blah"))` and I get a value. But once the page has loaded, typing `Math.isNumber` into Firefox's web console yields `undefined`. In Chrome, it returns the function I set above. Why?

Comment: Why attach it to `Math`? What is this for? The name `isNumber` is misleading, doesn't make much sense since you're passing _a number_ as parameter.

Comment: This isn't code that I'm actually using in anything, so that is pretty much irrelevant. The real point of this question is to find out why Firefox behaves in this way. But yes, you are right, it would be illogical to name the parameter number.

Comment: It works fine for me in FF 16.

Comment: I tried it in FF 16.0.2 under a clean profile and it does not work. To confirm: did you wait until the page had loaded and then try using the method within the FF console (Ctrl+Shift+K)? When I try actually using it, I get "TypeError: Math.isNumber is not a function". When I try `typeof Math.isNumber` in the console, I get "undefined".

Comment: I tried in JSBIN http://jsbin.com/oqayot/1/edit

Comment: Yeah, that seems to log the function in the console. Now try doing that manually. I get undefined.

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar: Where are you doing your actual testing. Sites like jsFiddle and jsBin run the code in a frame, so there's a separate JS environment from the console.

Comment: Ok, that's odd considering I also tried it in Firefox Aurora 18.0a2 and Firefox 10.0.10 (ESR) with both giving me undefined. I'll try reinstalling Firefox, clearing cache, etc. Thanks for the help. If I still can't figure it out, I'll open a bounty at some point.

Comment: What OS are you on? I don't see why it wouldn't work but I'm on linux FF 16 and works as well as Chrome 23

Comment: @user1689607: New HTML web page. Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/LsEWkt7q

Comment: @elclanrs: Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't show up for me in the console, but it works in code.

Comment: ...I take that back. I was using `document.write` in the head, but then I delayed it until after the DOM is loaded. If you're using `document.write` after the DOM is loaded, then that's why,.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I load the page, open the web console (Ctrl+Shift+K in Windows), type in `console.log(Math.isNumber(22));` and get a TypeError: Math.isNumber is not a function.

Comment: I also got Math.isNumber undefined, using the Web Console (Ctrl + Shift + K). I'm using FF 16.0.2 (Fedora 16). However, using Firebug's Console it works.

Comment: I also noticed that creating an object with a different name (for instance, new Test()) and decorating the object with the function, it works from the console. The Math object is a bit special, it's a static object and cannot be instantiated. My believe is that the implementation of the Math object in FF and in Webkit is different, but the fact that the object can be sucessfully inspected from Firefox Firebug puzzles me a bit.

Comment: I wonder if this is non-standard behaviour -- or indeed if there is a defined standard for special objects.